# how to select records in MySQL where the occurrence of foreign key is only one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my MQL database with foreign keys. Now I want to select the records form this MySQL tables using join where the occurrence of a specific foreign key is only one and skip the records where occurrence is more than 1.

For example if I use simple select query like

```
Select * 
from table1 
INNER Join table2 on table1.id=table2.id 
where group_id=1
```

it selects all the records where group_id is 1 and also those where others group_ids exists I mean more than one gourp_ids against the same foreign key.
is there any solution.

Comment: Please post table description data examples and expected result in text format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GROUP BY ... HAVING ... syntax is exactly for this purpose:

```
Select table1.id 
from table1 
INNER Join table2 
on table1.id=table2.id 
where group_id=1
group by table2.id
having count(*)=1
```